# How do I create a relation between tables using an interval comparison in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I would like to create a relationship between two tables based on whether a value in one table falls in a an interval in the other. One table 1 is ~16000 rows:

```
name     | start        | end
-----------------------------------------
someName | startPosition | endPosition
```

table 2 is ~20000000 rows:

```
id      | location
--------------------------
someID  | positionInteger
```

Each id falls in the interval of exactly one name, but each name can have many ids associated with it.

I would like to add a new index to table 2 so that it becomes:

```
id      | location        | name
---------------------------------
someID  | positionInteger | someName
```

I've tried doing:

```
ALTER TABLE table2 ADD INDEX name (name);
```

With a bit of python I can get all the names in the database and then for each name and interval:

```
SELECT someID FROM table2 WHERE location >= startPosition AND location <= endPosition
```

Then I can loop through the resulting IDs and:

```
UPDATE table2 SET name = 'someName' WHERE id = 'someID'
```

This works but is very slow. Is there a more efficient way to do this using MySQL and avoiding multiple loops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join the tables

```
SELECT t2.id, t2.location, t1.name
FROM Table1 AS t1
JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON t2.location BETWEEN t1.startPosition AND t1.endPosition
```

You shouldn't be adding an index to table 2, you should be adding a column:

```
ALTER TABLE Table2 ADD COLUMN name VARCHAR(32); -- Replace this with the actual size
```

Then you can update all the rows with a similar join:

```
UPDATE Table2 AS t2
JOIN Table1 AS t1 ON t2.location BETWEEN t1.startPosition AND t1.endPosition
SET t2.name = t1.name
```

Comment: Thank you. Both this solution and the one from I Putu Susila worked well. I was able to add the index to new column after the update

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` :

```
SELECT id,location,name FROM table2 as t2 
LEFT JOIN table1 as t1 
ON t2.location BETWEEN t1.`start` AND t1.`end`;
```

More details http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/721e5/1